# Is there a way to query the ordering of two cuda events?

Tags: cuda

Suppose we recorded two cuda events A and B by calling to cudaEventRecord, then before we do any synchronization, is there any way to judge whether A will necessarily happen before or after B? For example, if I have these code:

```
kernelA<<<1,1>>>(...);
cudaEventRecord(A, 0);
kernelB<<<1,1>>>(...);
cudaEventRecord(B, 0);
```

Then B should happen after A for sure, but how would I know this given the two handles? In another way, how would I write a function like this:

```
bool judge_order(cudaEvent_t A, cudaEvent_t B) {...}
```

Such that it returns true if A would happen before B.

The question arises when I want to make a memory manager in order to effectively reuse the memory that are already used in the previous kernel launches.

Comment: I don't think it's possible simply by inspecting the events themselves.  The event structure is opaque, and you are limited to what is expressed via the [event API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT).  However you could build a wrapper macro or some wrapper function which timestamped each call to `cudaEventRecord, and stored away in a table the event handle, the timestamp, and the stream ID, and build your own `judge_order` function based on that table.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I was wondering if cuda has this support. Now that it does not, I will implement mine as you described!

Answer (score 1):

Everything in CUDA is scheduled on streams. This includes kernel execution, memory transfer, and events. By default everything operates on stream 0.

Each stream is processed stricly linear. I.e. in your example it is guaranteed that kernelA has been completed before eventA is processed. By querying the status of an event you can tell if it has been processd without waiting for it.

Separate streams however can be processed in any order. If you would use a separate stream for each of your kernels/events then no particular processing order is guaranteed.

All of this is much better explained in the CUDA programming guide.

Comment: Thank you! But if I received two event handles, A and B, how would I tell which happens first? In another way, how would I write this function: `bool get_order(cudaEvent_t A, cudaEvent_t B) {}`, which returns true if A happens before B?

Comment: As far as I know there is no API to compare the "position on stream" for events. You will have to remember the order in which you scheduled them yourself. And if they are on separate streams the order is undefined!

Comment: @shaoyl85 - if both events already happened you could compare it against arbitrary 'start' event and check how much time elapsed by `cudaEventElapsedTime`.